# How can partials inherit events in RactiveJS

Tags: ractivejs

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory, I've been playing with RactiveJS for a while now and I still didn't manage to figure out how could partials inherit parent events.

There's no reason for a jsfiddle because it's no particular problem.

### someTemplate:

```
<div id="container">{{ > somePartial }}</div>
```

### somePartialContent:

```
<div id="testMessage" on-click="showMessage:hello">click me</div>
```

### Then running this:

```
var content = new Ractive({
    el : 'body',
    template : someTemplate,
    partials : { somePartial : somePartialContent }
});
content.on({ showMessage: function( e , _message ) { alert( _message ) } });
```

The expected behaviour is that when I click `#testMessage` an alert box would pop up , but it doesnt.

Comment: It works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/905w350x/ - which version are you using?